# Mock the `fileno` method of a Python 2 `file` object

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-2.x

How can I use `mock.patch` to wrap the `file.fileno` method on a [Python 2 file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)?

When I attempt to use the normal `mock.patch.object` on the `file` instance:

```python
# file-fileno-mock.py

import sys
import tempfile

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    import mock
else:
    from unittest import mock


(foo_fileno, foo_file_path) = tempfile.mkstemp()

# Open the temporary file path and get a real file object.
with open(foo_file_path) as foo_file:
    # Patch a single attribute on the real `foo_file` object.
    with mock.patch.object(foo_file, 'fileno'):
        # Access the `fileno` method and call it,
        # which because of the mock wrapper will call a mock method instead.
        fake_foo_fileno = foo_file.fileno()
        assert fake_foo_fileno != foo_fileno
```

That works in Python 3, but in Python 2 it raises an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file-fileno-mock.py", line 15, in <module>
    with mock.patch.object(foo_file, 'fileno'):
  File "[…]/mock/mock.py", line 1460, in __enter__
    setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)
AttributeError: 'file' object attribute 'fileno' is read-only
```

Evidently `mock.patch` is attempting to write the `foo_file.fileno`
attribute; the Python 2 `file` type disallows that, the [Python 3
equivalent](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python3/html/library/io.html#io.FileIO) allows it.

How can I [use `mock.patch` as intended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object), on a Python 2 `file` object,
without running afoul of this special limitation in Python 2 `file`?

Comment: `fake_foo_fileno = StringIO.StringIO()`? It needs to be a writeable object, you can either simulate a class with write/read attributes, and/or copy the `StringIO` class but replace the handling of in/out data.

Comment: I have tried to use mock.patch to test modules that interact with the filesystem and gave up. Instead I switched to http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/index.html and my life became much easier!

Comment: I think you should just mock the file, and maybe use spec with it. even with a list of valid string attributes. That way you really don't touch the filesystem. Then check your mock usage. Instead of mocking inside the real object.